# Similar Uses Case. How do the better solution?

Tags: uml, use-case, visual-paradigm

For my project i need to do Uses Case Diagram.
These are my uses cases but i think this solution isnt correct.
[image: Cliente use case]

**Search shop** -> Cliente find all shop in the system

**Search shop in your city** -> Cliente  find shop of his city

**Search shop in by city by category** -> Cliente find shop in a input city with an input category

**Search shop by category** -> Cliente find all shop with the input category

I was thinking of using an extension as they basically do the same thing but some with some different steps.

From mine definition: Alternative or optional behaviors of a use case set of use cases that extend the general use case

So i think like this

[image]

But i dont know if my solution is right or not because i'm not sure about <>

The client must be able to do these 4 searches.

Is it better the first or second solution? And why?
Are there other better solutions?

EDIT: I'm trying a new solution.

**Mine problem: Cliente can make different searches in the system.**

[image]

[image]

Adding scenarios to mine UC could be better than other solution? I know that an UC can have various extensions of both success and failure.
Could I solve my problems by opting for a solution like this?

Comment: You should not fall in the trap of functional deecomposition. Think over how much added value you get for the different variants. Likely you can stay with the basic UC `Search shop` and describe the variants just inside. It's difficult to give advise since it much depends on context. Since you have it under Flow of events I would assume they are just different paths of the same use case.

Comment: @qwerty_so thanks for explain. My project offers 4 different search possibilities, based on what the user wants to do. I think the solution with 4 different flow events might be correct, but I can't figure out for sure if this is possible

Comment: A UC shows a single added piece of value the system under consideration offers to an actor. Definition of that will vary. But people often start functional decomposition which is wrong. A good read to recommend is Bittner/Spence about use cases. They just nailed it. P.S. If your UC diagram resembles a spider web this indicates a broken design.

Comment: @qwerty_so to be honest, the initial four use cases add a single real added value, that is, research a store. If I talked about "Search shop" then this would be an added value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to express another viewpoint in addition to [Bruno](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66243273/3723423)’s expert and comprehensive answer.

While UML is agnostic of what a use-case should or should not express, there is a wide understanding that use-cases should correspond to actor **goals**.

When I personally look for a shop, my primary goal is to find a shop. The criteria are just means to achieve this goal. Maybe a shop in my town, maybe the shop closest to my GPS coordinates, maybe I’m looking for a given category, or maybe I will refine my criteria interactively while search results are displayed.

Specifying use-cases that are too detailed will lock you very early into a solution that might pre-define or [constrain your user-interface](https://doi.org/10.1145/205350.205356) without really having thought about the best and most comfortable way to achieve the goal for the user.  The UML founders warned against this drawback and explicitly recommended not to use use-case models for designing a user interface.

I’d therefore keep it simple and just have a use-case `Search shop`, and describe the more specific intents/expectations in the description associated to each UC (preferably using [essential use-cases](http://agilemodeling.com/artifacts/essentialUseCase.htm)).

Comment: Thanks, so if i have 4 types of searches i dont explain all of that but it's enough explain the "idea" of seach shop?

Comment: @MrBuffalo exactly! And you can see that the search of shop by GPS on your mobile is not in your identified list. But it’s the first thing that mobile users expect. If you keep the idea abstract, you’ll be more open to such ideas. And your software design would also stay more general and able to cope with such evolutions (e.g. using the more generic [query pattern](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/queryObject.html))  :-)

Comment: Great! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

All depends on what you want to show.

A said by the standard (§18.1.3.2 page 640 of [formal/2017-12-05](https:///www.omg.org/spec/UML)) :

> Extend is intended to be used when there is some additional behavior that should be added, possibly conditionally, to the behavior defined in one or more UseCases.

So, your second diagram is not equivalent to your first diagram (supposing the use cases unchanged):

- in the first diagram the client *search shop* **or** *search shop in your city* **or** *search shop by category* **or** ...
- in the second diagram when a client *search shop* during it he can also *search shop in your city* **and** can also *search shop by category* **and** ...

Perhaps you wanted to say during the search it is possible to add filter to search in the city and/or in a category, in that case you can use 2 extends:

[image]

Note *search shop in city* and *search shop by category* are specialization of *search shop*, and *search shop in city by category* a specialization of *search shop in city* and *search shop by category*, so:

[image]

if you very like generalization in UC

---

Out of these theoretical considerations about extend/generalization and looking at the UCs by themselves, like in any case about UC, you have to check your UCs are effectively UC, do each has enough plus-value to exist or do you only have the UC *search shop* ?

Comment: thanks for the reply. So if i use the first solution it's right too. But im not sure about their names and this is mine biggest doubt. Is it valid? My project allows the Cliente to choose one of the four types. These are syntactically similar but simply show different searches.

Comment: @MrBuffalo The second case is 'strange' in the sense the name of the extending UCs are not clear, they are not a real search for me else thy cannot be fully added which is the role of the extend

Comment: In my opinion 2nd solution is helpful if i want add some filters like city and category.. But i dont really want do it. I want make different searches, so i think it's better first solution. Right?

Comment: @MrBuffalo in that case yes the first is what you want. Perhaps also consider generalizations, it may be practical to have "search shop in city" specializing "search shop" etc

Comment: maybe generalization could be better.  **search shop** is abstract and i can make the 4 different searches. So in this case I would have that: Search shop defines the main flow and the 4 alternatives define each case. This is right?

Comment: Neither of the `Set` bubbles contains a use case. Both are functions.

Comment: @MrBuffalo what is an abstract UC ?

Comment: @bruno it's a UC with different specialization. isnt it?

Comment: @MrBuffalo in my second diagram yes, but it is not abstract and for me abstract UC does not exist (I can be wrong of course)

Comment: @bruno im not completely sure about my 4 uses case... they are similar but with a bit difference (all, by city, by category...). Surely i need to review my UCs

Comment: @bruno can i create only **search shop** and use other scenarios to explain that? I dont think each one add plus-value

Comment: @MrBuffalo They are a lot of discussions about UCs, about what is an UC and what is not, as you can see  qwerty_so do not agree with my UC "set X", and perhaps he is right. Probably *search shop* alone is enough, the fact it is possible to filter is just part of the UC ... among other details

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228860/discussion-between-mrbuffalo-and-bruno).